# How to apply update to Parse server hosted on Heroku?

Tags: xcode, parse-server

I want to apply the changes listed here https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/3150/files as my parse server currently only returns a maximum of 100 objects.

How do I update my parse server with these changes?

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json if you have

```
"parse-server": "*",
```

Remove this line and type:

npm install git+https://github.com/JulienKode/parse-server.git

To be sure that you have the changes that you want:

go to node_modules/parse-server/lib/Routers/ClassesRouter.js

And see the query limit

Comment: I have `"parse-server": "^2.2.25"` in package.json. What do I need to type?

Comment: Replace by 2.4.2 or * as I mentioned

Comment: I replaced this as suggested however parse queries are still limited to 100. Is there a way to check the current version of the parse server so I can make sure it has updated to the latest version?

Comment: See my comment above, I believe the update worked however still returning a maximum of 100 objects.

Comment: Sorry my internet is so slow, have you type npm install ?

Comment: When you tape npm install you see the version of your packages

Comment: Yes. The part of package.json that I changed was under dependencies. Is this correct? Looking at the file, I think I am supposed to change `"version": "1.4.0"` and not `"parse-server": "^2.2.25"` ?

Comment: No this is the version of your package

Comment: The log following the `npm install` has `parse-server@2.4.2`. Any ideas why queries are still limited?

Comment: Oh I've just seen, the changes that you want was not merged ... So there are note available in parse-server from the community

Comment: Remove parse-server line in package.json and type npm install git+https://github.com/JulienKode/parse-server.git

Comment: I made the changes suggested however there is no longer a parse-server folder in node_modules and queries remain limited at 100.

Comment: there a miskate in my comment, have you type the same as my post ?
Can you show me the logs ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145571/discussion-between-user2562126-and-julien-kode).